# How create table inline function for security policy row filter depending on values in configuration table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, row-level-security, security-policy

I would like to create a row level security policy.

My input is a user_id for users who connect to the database through a middle-tier application.

I would like to:

1. Query a configuration table (let's call it `conf_table`) to get the department name of `user_id`
2. Depending on value `department`, I want to filter on another table called `customers` on `type_of_customers`.

Example:

`conf_table`:

| user_id | department |
| --- | --- |
| toto | sidney |

Customers:

| customer_no | typ_customer |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | A |
| 0002 | B |

Function:

```
IF conf_table.user_id = 'toto' AND conf_table.department = 'sidney'`
    SELECT * 
    FROM customers 
    WHERE typ_customer = A`

ELSE 
    SELECT * 
    FROM customers 
    WHERE typ_customer = B`
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to do this :

```
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(1) = 'B'

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM conf_table WHERE user_id = 'toto' AND department = 'sidney')
    SET @type = 'A'
    
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE typ_customer = @type
```

Comment: @iSR5 thank you for your answer! but I need to use a security policy object which depends on the user_id who queries the table "Customers" Do you know how make implement the same logic with a "CREATE SECURITY POLICY"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, yes I missed it

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, each row in `conf_table` would have a `typ_customer` associated with it, alternatively you would join to a `Departments` table to get that value.

But without that, you can just use a `CASE` expression.

Note the usage of a function parameter to be able to pass in the `typ_customer` value from the `Customers` table that is being filtered.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION Security.YourPredicateTVF (@typ_customer AS char(1))  
  RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS RETURN

SELECT 1 AS tvf_securitypredicate_result
FROM Security.conf_table c
WHERE c.user_id = USER_NAME()
  AND CASE c.department = 'sidney' THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END = @typ_customer;

GO
```

Then simply define a security policy, passing in the `typ_customer` column to the function.

```sql
CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security.YourPolicyName
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE
      Security.YourPredicateTVF (typ_customer)
      ON dbo.Customers;
```

You may want to change `FILTER` to `BLOCK` and/or add DML filters also, depending on your use case.

> Be aware that Row-Level Security is subject to side-channel attacks, and is therefore not a completely secure feature. For example, triggering a divide-by-zero error could tell the user what is stored in a row without actually seeing it.

Comment: Many thanks that was exactly what I needed! Thank you as well for your advice, what would be the alternative to row-level security ?